# Typescript type definition for moment.js durations

Tags: typescript, types, momentjs

I have implemented a module that takes two `moment.js` timestamps and a rounding rule and returns the rounded `moment.js` duration between those timestamps.

My first instinct was to use `moment.Moment` to specify the expected type of the output, as below.

```
export default function roundDuration(
  startTime: moment.Moment,
  endTime: moment.Moment,
  timeRoundingRule: number
): moment.Moment {
  const duration = moment.duration(endTime.diff(startTime));
  // calculate rounded duration based on rounding rule
  return roundedDuration;
}
```

But durations are different than moments.

On my spec file,

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import roundDuration from './rounding';

test('roundDuration rounds zero seconds to zero minutes duration using rule UpToNearestMinute', () => {
  const startTime = moment('05-17-2018 23:40:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss');
  const endTime = moment('05-17-2018 23:40:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY hh:mm:ss');
  const timeRoundingRule = 0;
  const roundedTime = roundDuration(startTime, endTime, timeRoundingRule);
  expect(roundedTime.asMinutes()).toBe(0);
});
```

I get the following linting error:

`[ts] Property 'asHours' does not exist on type 'Moment'. Did you mean 'hours'?`

Looking for or a specific types definition that would silence this error, like `moment.Moment.duration` or `moment.duration`:

```
export default function roundDuration(
    startTime: moment.Moment,
    endTime: moment.Moment,
    timeRoundingRule: number
): moment.Moment.duration { ... }
```

yields

`[ts] Namespace 'moment' has no exported member 'Moment'.`

or

`[ts] Namespace 'moment' has no exported member 'duration'.`

Which implementation would correct both errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your import being `import * as moment from 'moment'`, the type for Duration is `moment.Duration`, not `moment.duration`. Change this

```js
export default function roundDuration(
    startTime: moment.Moment,
    endTime: moment.Moment,
    timeRoundingRule: number
): moment.Moment.duration { ... }
```

to

```js
export default function roundDuration(
  startTime: moment.Moment,
  endTime: moment.Moment,
  timeRoundingRule: number
): moment.Duration{ ... }
```